Wordpress and CloudFront admin section, other routes and images don't work
I'm able to get a Wordpress site on AWS EC2 instance and have an Application Load Balancer serve the site. The URL looks something like this: Instan-Wordp-adfzcxvaqwer-52453245.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. This works as expected, all the routes work, I can login, create posts, etc.
At this point my UserData looks something like this (the database is in RDS):
    userData.addCommands(
      "yum update -y",
      "yum install -y httpd php php-mysqlnd",
      "systemctl start httpd",
      "systemctl enable httpd",
      "cd /var/www/html",
      "wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz",
      "tar -xzf latest.tar.gz",
      "cp -r wordpress/* /var/www/html/",
      "rm -rf wordpress",
      "rm -rf latest.tar.gz",
      "chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/",
      "sudo cp /var/www/html/wp-config-sample.php /var/www/html/wp-config.php",
      `sudo sed -i "s/'database_name_here'/'wordpress'/g" /var/www/html/wp-config.php`,
      `sudo sed -i "s/'username_here'/'admin'/g" /var/www/html/wp-config.php`,
      `sudo sed -i "s/'password_here'/'password#1'/g" /var/www/html/wp-config.php`,
      `sudo sed -i "s/'localhost'/'${props.db.dbInstanceEndpointAddress}'/g" /var/www/html/wp-config.php`,
      "systemctl restart httpd",
      "sudo usermod -a -G apache ec2-user",
      "sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www",
      "sudo chmod 2775 /var/www",
      "sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \\;",
      "sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \\;",
    );

The issue starts when I introduce CloudFront to this with a proper domain. I purchased the domain from GoDaddy (mygreatdomain.xyz). Here are the steps I followed:

I created the Hosted Zone:
    this.hostedZone = new HostedZone(
      this,
      this.setConstructName("HostedZone"),
      {
        zoneName: this.domainName,
      },
    );


Created the certificate:
    this.certificate = new Certificate(
      this,
      this.setConstructName("Certificate"),
      {
        domainName: this.domainName, // Root domain (mygreatdomain.xyz)
        subjectAlternativeNames: [`*.${this.domainName}`], // Wildcard domain (*.mygreatdomain.xyz)
        validation: CertificateValidation.fromDns(this.hostedZone),
      },
    );


Created Cloudfront Distribution
  private createCloudfrontDistributionAndARecord(
    alb: ApplicationLoadBalancer,
    props: InstanceStackProps,
  ): void {
    const distribution = new Distribution(
      this,
      this.setConstructName("Distribution"),
      {
        defaultBehavior: {
          origin: new LoadBalancerV2Origin(alb, {
            protocolPolicy: OriginProtocolPolicy.HTTP_ONLY,
          }),
          allowedMethods: AllowedMethods.ALLOW_ALL,
          viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
          cachePolicy: CachePolicy.CACHING_DISABLED,
          originRequestPolicy: OriginRequestPolicy.ALL_VIEWER,
        },
        domainNames: [`www.${this.domainName}`, this.domainName],
        certificate: props.certificate,
      },
    );

    // A Record for www
    new ARecord(this, "ARecord", {
      zone: props.hostedZone,
      target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(new CloudFrontTarget(distribution)),
      recordName: `www.${this.domainName}`,
    });

    // A Record for root domain
    new ARecord(this, "RootARecord", {
      zone: props.hostedZone,
      target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(new CloudFrontTarget(distribution)),
      recordName: this.domainName, // root domain
    });
  }



Adjusted wp-config.php to use the new domain
I added the following to the userData in the template:


`sudo sed -i "/define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );/a define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://${this.domainName}');" /var/www/html/wp-config.php`,
`sudo sed -i "/define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );/a define('WP_HOME', 'https://${this.domainName}');" /var/www/html/wp-config.php`,

At this point, the site renders (but none of the images do) nor can I log in to the admin section.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Try allowing the HOST and OPTIONS headers though your distribution. Also look at the HTML source of a page - if the URLs are broken, how they break might also give you clues (edit your question to add more info)

@MisterSmith, I do get this error when trying to login to the admin:
www.youramazingdomain.xyz redirected you too many times. Is there a fix for this in the distribution code above?
The links are all pointing to https://www.youramazingdomain.xyz/..... so not seeing an issue there

The fix will be allowing the HOST header (and OPTIONS  is a good idea too) - CF will be stripping them by default, so your wordpress on ec2 wont see the correct hostname of the originating request, hence the redirection loop. Youll need to define your own cachePolicy to allow headers using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudfront.CacheHeaderBehavior.html You might find this a useful template https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/how-to-accelerate-your-wordpress-site-with-amazon-cloudfront/ But you should write your own policy based on your own needs.

@MisterSmith, if you are familiar with CDK, could you adjust my code above to apply those changes?
